# I want to call multiple popups with minimal function

Tags: jquery, html

When you click onclick, you're popping up.
I want to use multiple popups and bring in different html files.
I don't know how to write the code.

```
// popup jquery
function layerPop(){
 $("body").append("<div class='popup_wrap'></div>");
 $(".popup_wrap").load("popup/marketing_agree.html");
}

function layerClose(){
 $(".popup_wrap").remove();
}

// popup btn
<i onclick="layerPop()"></i>

// popup/marketing_agree.html
 <div class="layer__pop__widget">
   <div class="pop__bg"></div>
   <div class="popup__widget consensual">
    <h3 class="popup__title"></h3>
    <div class="popup__contents">
     <button type="button" onclick="layerClose()" class="close__btn"></button>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

If you are currently running the source code, click on <i onclick = "layerPop" </i>
The layerPop function will run and .popup_wrap will be added to the popup/marking_agree.html. But I have a lot of pop-ups and there are many htmls to be added, so I wonder how to reduce reuse with code.

Comment: Do you want to add multiple popups with the same button? Explain this part a little please.

Comment: No! When layerPop() is run, different html must be present!
ex)
<i onclick="layerPop(popup1.html)">/i>
<i onclick="layerPop(popup2.html)">/i>
I'd like to do it this way or another way.
It's hard not to work like this.

Comment: In that case, you can keep use the approach depicted in my answer and use an associative array to map id to resource in the global scope in order to keep track of the resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One obvious way would be to accept params in your functions like this:

```
function layerPop(id, resource){
 $("body").append("<div class='popup_wrap' id=" + id +"></div>");
 $(".popup_wrap").load(resource);
}

function layerClose(id){
 if (id === null) $(".popup_wrap").remove();
 else $("#" + id).remove();
}
```

Then maybe maintain the resource location and id outside the function. This should give you a lot of code reusability.

```
layerPop("popup3", "popup/marketing_agree.html");
layerClose("popup3");
```

Comment: Thank you. It'll be useful for reference.